# R: predict function results varies between version, response out of bound (0-1)

Tags: r, statistics, predict

First, thank you for reading this.

I just bought a new computer and was in the process of installing the latest version of R (4.0.3) and Rstudio. I downloaded all my packages with **install.packages()**, the same packages I had on my old computer, so I downloaded the latest version for each package.

I opened a project and tried to run a script that already yielded results on my old computer. All the functions responded with the same results as my old computer except the **predict()** function.

The probabilities generated by the **predict()** function were not bounded between 0-1. Every output generated by Rstudio on my "new machine" were the same as the old one, except for the prediction.

```
# Create the probit model
myprobit <- glm(Delta ~ L4+L10, family = binomial(link = "probit"), 
                data = office_data)
### FINAL RESULTS ###
# Make predictions
probabilities <- myprobit %>% predict(final_model, type = "response")
probabilities<-probabilities[!is.na(probabilities)]
prob <- data.frame(probabilities)
```

The probabilities generated were:
(1. -1.519594872)
(2. -1.259374062)
(3. -0.825930396)
(4. -0.554464690)
(5.  0.338585816)
(6.  1.738214267)
(7.  2.538773665)
(8.  2.085306103)
(9.  1.719974131)
, ETC...

When the script was running on my old computer, the probabilities where bound between 0 and 1.

**This is what I tried so far**

**Previous Version Scenario**: I tried to download the previous version of library(stats) to match the one I had but my version was older than the limit fixed by Rstudio, I had 3.4.3 and I had an error stating that I needed a 3.5 version or higher. The new R (4.0.3) didn't support something older. It seams like most of my script run fine so I would like to keep the updated version of my packages, **I just want to know how to get proper probabilities from the predict() function**.

**Setup on Old computer**
R version 3.4.3
RStudio version 1.1.456 (2009-2018)
library(stats) 3.4.3

**Setup on New computer**
R version 4.0.3
RStudio version 1.1.456 (2009-2018)
library(stats) 4.0.3

**SO my question is: Was there a change between the version 3.4.3 and 4.0.3 that could have affected the predict() function? and how can I have probabilities as an output**

Lastly, this is a graph of my previous results
[Probabilities of a certain event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkWQE.png)

And this is my result with the new version and new computer
[Same code as before, except the value are now not in the probabiltie range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3TH4.png)

Thank you very much for your time. This is my first post on a forum.

Comment: Can you add a little example of your dataset so folks can run your model and make predictions to see what happens?  If you haven't done that before, see ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Also, what is `final_model` in your `predict()` code?  Is that the name of the new dataset you are using for predictions?

Comment: Hi aosmith, thank you for your response. I know that this is a common thing to do when troubleshooting a code, you need to recreate my environment and the data that I used. I cannot provide the dataset but I can say what it was like. I used a timeseries dataset with a single var

Comment: iable evolving over time. I stabilized it and build my in-sample and out-of-sample model. As I said, both model behaved normally and the predict function , used afterwards, gave me good probabilities. When I ran the same code on my new computer, everything was the same, all the numbers of my stabilized series were the same to the last digit. The only difference was the output of the predict function. To respond to your question, the`final_model`is a combination of all my available data (training and testing), I do not have enough data point to build a final model with 25% less data.

Comment: I managed to find my answer by deleting the libraries I was not using. I think it was a bad habit of mine to copy paste my libraries from one script to another and adding on top the new desired libraries. I think that I've messed with the different dependencies of certain libraries. Anyhow, thank you for your time @aosmith

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. For anyone who might have this problem, verify which library you load before running your code. In my case, I loaded too many libraries, I had some that were not used in my script.

I think that the priority of active function were messed up by loading too many libraries, althought I didn't have the problem on my old computer, the problem arised on the new one.